# Kendo Grid DataSource Selection based on condition

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a Kendo Grid and I want to switch DataSource based upon a flag value. I have created two DataSource Variables for this and passing them to Kendo Grid DataSource attribute based on the flag value. Something like this `dataSource: flag == 1 ? originalDataSource : backupDataSource`

```
var flag = 1;
//DataSource 1
var backupDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: "/MyController/MyAction1",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                ID : "1"
            },
        }
    },
    change: function (e) {},
    error: function () {},
    pageSize: 10,
    schema: {
        model: {
            fields: {
                Id: { type: "number" },
                Date: { type: "date" },
                Name: { type: "string" }
            },
        },
    }
});

// DataSource 2
var originalDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: "/MyController/MyAction2",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                ID : "1"
            },
        }
    },
    change: function (e) {},
    error: function () {},
    pageSize: 10,
    schema: {
        model: {
            fields: {
                Id: { type: "number" },
                Date: { type: "date" },
                Name: { type: "string" }
            },
        },
    }
});

//Calling Kendo Grid
$("#campaign-queue").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: flag == 1 ? originalDataSource : backupDataSource,
            filterable: true,
            sortable: true,
            columns: [
                {
                    field: "Id",
                    width: 55,
                    filterable: {
                        search: true,
                        extra: false
                    }
                },
                {
                    field: "Name",
                    width: 143,
                    filterable: {
                        extra: false
                    }
                }
            ],
            pageable: {
                previousNext: true,
                pageSize: 10
            }
        });
```

But this is not working as I am expecting. Only the `originalDataSource` is created but the `backupDataSource` is always coming to be null. What am I doing wrong? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with 'is always coming to be null' ? The variable value is null or the data are missing?

Comment: @GiovanniRomio The function `/MyController/MyAction1` is never called for the `backupDataSource` . So the variable turns out to be null.

Comment: What happens if you declare your dataSource: backupDataSource removing the conditional assignment?

Comment: Then it takes the `backupDataSource`. Only one of them will be initialised and the switching does not take place.

Comment: How do you switch between the two dataSources?

Comment: I want to switch the datasources based on the flag value. Don't know how that is going to happen. As of now I am trying to switch it using that ternary condition `dataSource: flag == 1 ? originalDataSource : backupDataSource1`

Comment: If I got it right you are trying to change the grid dataSource from originalDataSource to backupDataSource setting the flag to a value like 2. Correct me if i miss understood.

Comment: Yes exactly. You got it right !!

Comment: Javascript isn't intended to work like this. The ternary operator will be evaluated only once, when the grid is created. Consider to update the grid dataSource in a function triggered by any event. Then use the setOptions() function (https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/methods/setoptions) to change the dataSource.

Comment: Okay thanks. I will try this :)